# Display two unrelated tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables, sum, match, union

I have a problem with two different table sources that have no relation. I thought I would be able to use UNION.

I want to display both tables and match the nominal data. The data displayed is only date, code, nominal 1, nominal 2, and result.

I am using datatables on laravel 8

This is my Model:

```
class Fone extends Model
{
    protected $table = "fone";
    protected $fillable = ["date","f1","code","f2","cur","amount","region"];
}


class Gen extends Model
{
    protected $table = "gen";
    protected $fillable = ["date","g1","g2","g3","g4","amount","g5","code","cur","region"];
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function getdatamatch() 
    {
$fone = DB::table('fone')
            ->select('fone.date','fone.code', DB::raw('SUM(fone.amount) as amount'))
            ->groupBy('date', 'code');
        $gen = DB::table('gen')
            ->select('gen.date','gen.code', DB::raw('SUM(genacct.amount) as amount'))
            ->groupBy('date', 'code')
            ->union($fone)
            ->get();


        return Datatables::of($gen)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('result')
            ->make(true);
    }
```

This my View:

```
<table id="datatable_match" class="table dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                                 
                                <th>DATE</th>   
                                <th>CODE</th>                        
                                <th>AMOUNT FONE</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT GEN</th> 
                                 <th>RESULT</th>                
                            </tr> 
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>                                 
                                <th>DATE</th>   
                                <th>CODE</th>                        
                                <th>AMOUNT FONE</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT GEN</th> 
                               <th>RESULT</th>                 
                            </tr> 
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                  
                        </tbody>
                 
                    </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datatable_match').DataTable({
            pageLength: 3,
            responsive:true,
            processing:true,
            serverside:true,
            ajax:"{{route('ajax.get.data.match')}}",

            columns:[
                {data:'date',name:'date'},
                {data:'code',name:'code'},
                {data:'fone.amount',name:'fone.amount',
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 2, 'Rp.' )    
                    },
                {data:'gen.amount',name:'gen.amount',
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 2, 'Rp.' )    
                    },  
    {data:'result',name:'result'}, 
            ],
});
    });
```

Fone Table

```
DATE        F1  CODE    F2  CUR AMOUNT  REGION
2020-12-02  0001    100003  0000    IDR -100.00 JAKARTA
2020-12-02  0002    100003  0000    IDR -200.00 BANDUNG
2020-12-02  0002    100006  0000    IDR -300.00 BANDUNG
2020-12-02  0002    100008  0000    IDR -400.00 BANDUNG
2020-12-02  0003    100003  0000    IDR 0.00    PALEMBANG
2020-12-02  0003    100006  0000    IDR -500.00 PALEMBANG
2020-12-02  0003    100008  0000    IDR -600.00 PALEMBANG
```

Gen Table

```
DATE        G1          G2  G3      G4  AMOUNT  G5  CODE    CUR REGION
2020-12-02  009JKLMNOPQRSTU     1000    03AB    009ABCDEFGHI    -600.00 0001    100008  IDR PALEMBANG
2020-12-02  004JKLMNOPQRSTU     1000    06AB    000ABCDEFGHI    -200.00 0001    100003  IDR BANDUNG
2020-12-02  007JKLMNOPQRSTU     1000    08AB    076ABCDEFGHI    0.00    0001    100003  IDR PALEMBANG
2020-12-02  006JKLMNOPQRSTU     1000    08AB    076ABCDEFGHI    -400.00 0001    100008  IDR BANDUNG
2020-12-02  008JKLMNOPQRSTU     1000    08AB    076ABCDEFGHI    -500.00 0001    100006  IDR PALEMBANG
2020-12-02  005JKLMNOPQRSTU     1000    06AB    012ABCDEFGHI    -300.00 0001    100006  IDR BANDUNG
2020-12-02  003JKLMNOPQRSTU     1000    06AB    026ABCDEFGHI    -100.00 0001    100003  IDR JAKARTA
```

I want to display data group by date and code with SUM amount.
If the nominal is the same then the result is MATCH. But if it doesn't match, it will be written NOT MATCH.

```
DATE        CODE    AMOUNT_FONE AMOUNT_GEN  RESULT
2020-12-02  100003  -300.00     -300.00     MATCH
2020-12-02  100006  -800.00     -800.00     MATCH
2020-12-02  100008  -1000.00    -1000.00    MATCH
```

The problem is that I can't display AMOUNT from the Gen Table yet and match the results of the two nominal values.

Kindly help me to bring up this solution. Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Finally I created a code table for the relation. However, SUM and RESULT are not yet running.

```
$code = Code::join('gen','gen.id','=','code.id')
            ->join('fone','fone.id','=','code.id')
            ->select('fone.date','code', Fone::raw('SUM(fone.amount) as amount_fone'), Gen::raw('SUM(gen.amount) as amount_gen'))
            ->groupBy('date', 'code')
            ->get();
```

But what running on is

```
DATE        CODE    AMOUNT_FONE AMOUNT_GEN  RESULT
    2020-12-02  100003  -100.00     -100.00     
    2020-12-02  100006  -200.00     -200.00     
    2020-12-02  100008  -300.00     -300.00
```

if according to calculations

```
100003  = -100.00 + -200.00 + 0.00 = -300.00 (query SUM = -100.00)
100006  = -300.00 + -500.00 = -800.00 (query SUM = -200.00)
100008  = -400.00 + -600.00 = -1000.00 (query SUM = -300.00)
```

Comment: So if you need to treat the two tables differently, don't use a union query. Work with the results of the two queries to build a single result.

Comment: oh like that, more precisely what kind of query can you use?

Comment: I don't know, it's not my data. I expect you could use the same queries and then perform whatever business logic you need on the data to get your end result.

Comment: hi, finally i'm create tabel code for join relation. But SUM is still wrong and there is no RESULT column